# How can we get the list of neighborhoods for the different governorates in Jordan according to Google Geocode info?

Tags: google-geolocation

we are developing an e-commerce app for android & iOS & we need to get the Google Maps location of the customer ( currently we are trying to fetch the neighborhood ) to price the cost of delivery to their location,  how can we get the list of neighborhoods for the different governorates in Jordan?

We tried the following API, using our key instead of the XXXXX

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=neighborhoods+in%20+Amman,+Jordan&key=XXXXX

but we didn't get the full list, seems what they provided is a sample here.

Will need the list also for other governorates other than Amman.